# Using javascript for multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to handle several elements that require a specific functionality in our development stage for toggle-like buttons that open and close divs. I say toggle-like because it isn't your standard toggle setup.

The code I have works for a single instance of the buttons and container. Now I need to learn how to apply this to a dozen more which should function independent of each other.

This fiddle shows four examples where the first CSS button is the only one working.

https://jsfiddle.net/e2fexbqp/12/

This is the code that is creating the working example of a single block - two buttons and our div - which should be functional for several other button / div areas.

**HTML**

```
<a class="button" id="open">Open</a>

<div id="click-drop" style="display:none">

<h2>Hello World</h2>
<p>You can see me! I'm open! Type your code below.</p>
<textarea></textarea>
<p><a class="button" id="close" style="display:none">Close</a></p>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var open = document.getElementById("open");
var close = document.getElementById("close");

function show(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'block';
}
function hide(target) {
    document.getElementById(target).style.display = 'none';
}
function hideButton() {
    var x = document.getElementById("open");
    x.style.display = "none";
    var x = document.getElementById("close");
    x.style.display = "";
}
function showButton() {
    var x = document.getElementById("open");
    x.style.display = "";
    var x = document.getElementById("close");
    x.style.display = "none";
}
open.onclick = function() {show('click-drop');hideButton()}
close.onclick = function() {hide('click-drop');showButton()
```

I would like something clean and concise as well as unobtrusive.

Comment: Use `class`..Iterate through elements.. And register event listeners...I would suggest to use `jQuery`

Comment: Would you like many opened at the same time or only one ?

Comment: As many as the user wants to remain open is desired.

Comment: > whatever the com shares as is best practice for implementing. Define *com shares*?

Comment: Revised the question: community shares

Comment: Interesting question however, asking this question in programmers stackexchange will fetch you more appropriate response. Your question is highly opinion based. Server load vs Client usability. <<Civil war>>

Answer (score 1):

This demo is pure JavaScript as it is indicated in the tags and implied by the provided code in the question. It has **only one `eventListener` and multiple `event.targets`** BTW, unique ids can only be given to one element. **You cannot have multiple ids with the same value**. So you'll notice I used only classes no ids.

**Advantages**

- Pure JavaScript and no dependencies on plugins.
- Cross-browser with modern browsers.
- Having to use only one eventListener is very memory efficient.
- It determines exactly which button is clicked without creating an array, or NodeList to iterate through in a loop.

**Disadvantages**

- If you need to be compatible with IE9, then `classList` has to be replaced with `className`.
- The HTML layout must be in strict pattern. Key elements must be positioned in a predetermined sequence. That's not much of a problem if you have a habit of making organized patterns in markup.

Step by step description is commented in the source.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/16nLoz0t/)

**SNIPPET**

```js
// Reference the parent element

var box = document.querySelector('.box');
// add an eventListener to parent

box.addEventListener('click', toggleBtn, false);

function toggleBtn(event) {
  /* This will prevent the <a>nchors from 
   behaving like normal anchors which
   jump from one location to another
  */
  event.preventDefault();
  // event.target is the element that was clicked (.open/.close .button)
  // event.currentTarget is the element that listens for an event (.box)

  if (event.target != event.currentTarget) {
    var clicked = event.target;

    /* If the clicked element has .open class
     find the sibling element that was before it and
     show it by adding .show class and removing .hide
     Then hide clicked element.
    */
    if (clicked.classList.contains('open')) {
      var drop = clicked.previousElementSibling;
      drop.classList.remove('hide');
      drop.classList.add('show');
      clicked.classList.remove('show');
      clicked.classList.add('hide');
    } else {
      /* Else find clicked parent and hide it
       and then show the parent's sibling that is after it.
      */
      var drop = clicked.parentElement;
      var open = drop.nextElementSibling;
      drop.classList.remove('show');
      drop.classList.add('hide');
      open.classList.remove('hide');
      open.classList.add('show');
    }
  }
  /* This prevents the bubbling phase from continuing
   up the event chain and triggering any unnecessary
   eventListeners
  */
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

```css
* {
  /* Prefix no longer needed */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box {
  /* Just for demo */
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
.button {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 26px;
  height: 28px;
  width: 48px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  /* Prefix no longer needed for years */
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
}
.click-drop {
  border: solid 1px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
.button.show {
  display: inline-block;
}
.close {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--[The order in which elements are positioned is important which will be evident when you review the JavaScript]-->

<!--.box is the 'ancestor/parent' element and event.currentTarget-->

<section class="box">
  <h1>Header Content</h1>
  <!--Each .click-drop is initially hidden hence it has .hide as a class as well-->

  <div class="click-drop hide">
    <!--All descendants/children of each .click-drop inherits display:none prop/val from .click-drop.hide-->

    <p>Header style</p>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <a class="close button">Close</a>
  </div>
  <!--Each .open.button follows it's corresponding .click-drop-->

  <a class="open button show">CSS</a>


  <div class="click-drop hide">
    <p>Header content</p>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <a class="close button">Close</a>
  </div>
  <a class="open button show">HTML</a>

  <h1>Footer Content</h1>

  <div class="click-drop hide">
    <p>Footer style</p>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <a class="close button">Close</a>
  </div>
  <a class="open button show">CSS</a>


  <div class="click-drop hide">
    <p>Footer content</p>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <a class="close button">Close</a>
  </div>
  <a class="open button show">HTML</a>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's explain some points :

1. IDs in HTML, in a page, shall be unique.
2. Using classes and jQuery you can achieve this pretty much easily.
3. I added a span over all the "open button + its corresponding zone" that I set a "zone" class
4. I put an "open" class to all open links.
5. I put a "close" class to all close links.
6. I registered the click for '.zone .open' elements so they hide themselves  and show the contained DIV in their parent.
7. I registered the click for '.zone .close' elements so they hide the DIV under '.zone' element containing them and show the '.open' link under them.

So here is what I've done :
https://jsfiddle.net/e2fexbqp/13/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.zone .open').click(function() {
   $(this).hide();
    $(this).parent().find('div').show();
  });
  $('.zone .close').click(function() {
   var parent = $(this).parents('.zone');
   parent.children('div').hide();
    parent.children('a.open').show();
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 26px;
    height: 28px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 10px 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.zone div {
    border: solid 1px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Header Content</h1>

<span class="zone">
<a class="button open">CSS</a>

<div>
                    
<p>Header style</p>
<textarea></textarea>
<p><a class="button close">Close</a></p>
    
</div>
</span>

<span class="zone">
<a class="button open">HTML</a>

<div>
<p>Header content</p>
<textarea></textarea>
<p><a class="button close">Close</a></p>
    
</div>
</span>
<h1>Footer Content</h1>
<span class="zone">
<a class="button open">CSS</a>

<div>
                    
<p>Footer style</p>
<textarea></textarea>
<p><a class="button close">Close</a></p>
    
</div> 
</span><span class="zone">
<a class="button open">HTML</a>

<div>
                    
<p>Footer content</p>
<textarea></textarea>
<p><a class="button close">Close</a></p>
    
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: Ahh! It works. I will check it out on our development stage and check back when I'm at the computer. Ty!

Comment: If you find the answer correct, don't forget to accept it (and maybe vote up)

Comment: Absolutely. I'm mobile and will circle back tomorrow. Thanks again.

Comment: do you mind supporting your answer in comparison to the answer provided by zer00ne? Since you answered first I thought I would give you an opportunity to respond.

Comment: Well, I would say this : Considering that multiple sites use jQuery, it is likely that this file would already be downloaded. So, it makes less download for the internaut that visits your website because this code is smaller. And if your site is visited a lot, it makes a considerable difference for you.

Comment: That was my conclusion. It's lighter and my network already includes the jQuery library so there's nothing extra to load there.

Answer (score 0):

Use event target to style the individual element that got clicked.

```
anchors = doc.getElementsByClassName("button");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {    
    anchors[i].addEventListener("click", function(e){
        e.target.classList.toggle('hide');
    });
}
```